# can I use llvm ir in another language project?

Tags: llvm

I read that llvm is backend having multiple frontend, c, c++, swift ...
So, can I convert ir code based something to ir code based another?
Or, can I just use ir code in different language project?

Comment: If you meant to ask whether you can generate IR in a commit for a new language: yes you can. If not, then you might perhaps clarify your question.

Comment: I mean it is possible to use ir code generated such language in another frontend.

Comment: You can. It's not simple. For example, mapping inheritance, structure layout or exception handling will keep you busy. But it can be done.